# Simple Optimization Problem with linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm asked to find that the  solution of $\displaystyle S(\mathbf{c})=\max_{\mathbf{c}}\frac{\mathbf{X' Z c}}{||\mathbf{X}||\cdot||\mathbf{Z c}||}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times1$ vector, and $\mathbf{c}$ is a $m\times1$ vector, is the vector $\mathbf{Z}(\mathbf{Z}'\mathbf{Z})^{-1}\mathbf{Z}'\mathbf{X}$.

I dont' seem to understand how to do it. First I've tried reducing the problem only to $||Zc||=1$ and $||X||=1$, but then I get from the first order derivative condition $X'Z=0$. (!?)

Then I tried another approach.

I derived w.r.t. $c$ the original maximization problem, i.e., 
$S'(c)=0\Leftrightarrow X'X \sqrt{c'Z'Zc}=X'Zc\sqrt{X'X}c'Z'Z$, but this doesn't seem to be closer to what I need...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Axel, Z is a $n\times m$ matrix. It doesn't necessarily have an inverse...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthsea:  Do you not want to maximize over $X$ for fixed $c$? Note also that $S$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $Z\in M_{n,m}$, $X^TZ\not=0$, $Z^TZ$ is invertible (that is $rank(Z)=m\leq n$) and $||.||$ is the euclidean norm. Let $f(c)=\dfrac{X^TZc}{||X||||Zc||}$. We show that $\max(f)$ is reached for $c=(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX$. It is sufficient to consider the function $f$ over the compact $\{c:||c||=a\;positive\;constant\}$. Then $\max(f)$ is reached on such a ball. We search $\max(f)$ under the condition $g(c)=||Zc||^2-1=0$. Using Lagrange's theory, we obtain:

$Df_c+\lambda Dg_c=0$, that is $\dfrac{X^TZ}{||Zc||}-\dfrac{X^TZc(Zc)^TZ}{||Zc||^3}+\lambda c^T(Z^TZ)=0$ or $X^TZ=c^T(Z^TZ)(X^TZc-\lambda)$, that is, $Z^TZc=\alpha Z^TX$ where $\alpha$ is non-zero real ($Z^TX\not=0$). Up to a multiplication by a positive number, there are $2$ solutions for $c$: $c_+= (Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX,c_-=-(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX$. Note that $X^TZc_+=X^TZ(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX>0$ because $(Z^TZ)^{-1}$ is symmetric $> 0$. Finally $f(c_+)=\max (f),f(c_-)=\min(f)$.